# Firefox unable to connect ssl

Tags: linux, ssl, firefox, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to setup my site through ssl. Apache starts without trouble but firefox gives me the following error:

'Unable to connect'.

My virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/site
ServerName site.nl
ServerAlias www.site.nl
SSLEngine ON
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.nl/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.nl/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/site
ServerName site.nl
ServerAlias www.site.nl
</VirtualHost>
```

ports.conf:

Listen 80 443

I'm in the beta of letsencrypt.org.

Running apache2 on Linux

I have tried about everything there is to find about this on google.

Note: it connects fine through http (without ssl, port 80)

Comment: 1) Can you telnet port 443 of your server from the machine from where you're connecting with firefox?
2) If the machine you're using firefox has linux, try this:
  openssl s_client -connect https://YOURSERVERHOSTNAME
and check that it works, showing you the server pubblic cert, CN and such.

Comment: Telnet tells me "connection refused". I am running Linux (both laptop and server) but the command with openssl just prints out the how to use stuff so I'll have to look into that more at least.

Comment: I bet you dont have mod_ssl loaded. [EDIT] you have both ports in the same Listen directove? Try putting two lines:
Listen 80
Listen 443

Comment: a2enmod ssl gives me: Module ssl already enabled.

Comment: I replied too fast, as for my edit, try putting two Listen lines, one for each of 80 and 443

Comment: At least no 'connection refused' anymore. I'm now getting: 'ssl_error_rx_record_too_long'.

Comment: That's because for some reason you don't have HTTPS enabled on that port, to check for this, try with firefox: http://yourserver:443/ (Yes, HTTP not HTTPS)

Comment: That is working fine, do you have any idea how I can enable https on port 443? (google isn't really helping me out)

Comment: Check apachectl -S , you should see both virtual hosts

Comment: @AlexisWilke `<VirtualHost>` expects an IP address/port (or wildcard for each of those), or `_default_`. Names are not used here in modern versions of Apache, and URLs were never used.

Comment: @AlexisWilke That seems to work! It's just untrusted while it should be trusted but thank you!